# Unable to disable System restore point

Tags: c++, winapi

```
DWORD Val = 0;
HKEY dwo;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\SystemRestore", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &dwo);
RegSetValueEx(dwo, "TurnOffSystemRestore", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&Val, sizeof(DWORD));
RegCloseKey(dwo);
```

Hello, I want to disable System restore but I can't do that and
I think i have to change TurnOffSystemRestore to something else, and maybe it's not correct at all
so how to do that correctly?

Comment: `RegSetValueEx(dwo, "TurnOffSystemRestore", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&Val, sizeof(DWORD));` I would expect setting a value to `0` disables the setting.

Comment: ***Set the value to 1 to disable System Restore or 0 to enable System Restore*** here: [https://www.itprotoday.com/cloud-computing/how-do-i-enable-and-disable-windows-xps-system-restore-feature](https://www.itprotoday.com/cloud-computing/how-do-i-enable-and-disable-windows-xps-system-restore-feature)

Comment: @drescherjm I set the DWORD  Val to 0 and 1, i tested both and not working at all, are u sure about `TurnOffSystemRestore` ? I think it's wrong

Comment: It appears to have worked on windows XP but not sure about a modern OS. Did you reboot after changing the setting? Did you also run this in a program that has UAC elevation?

Comment: @drescherjm not working for me again but thank you for helping

Comment: @drescherjm oops I was right turnOffSystemRestore is not correct must change to DisableSR and will work :)

Comment: This is not a programming problem. The code seems to behave as you'd expect. This is really a question about general computing, i.e. what value do you need to write to a registry key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

```
DWORD Val = 1; //set the value to 0 to enable
HKEY dwo;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\SystemRestore", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &dwo);
RegSetValueEx(dwo, "DisableSR", 0, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&Val, sizeof(DWORD));
RegCloseKey(dwo);
```